# String replace method is not working in android studio

Tags: java, android, string

I'm not too sure why my word doesn't get replaced in android studio.

```
    private Calendar dateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy, EEE");
    String dateFormat = dateFormatter.format(dateTime.getTime());
    Button beginDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startDate);
    beginDate.setText("From     " + dateFormat);

    // Other codes removed for simplicity

    String beginD = beginDate.getText().toString().replace("From:     ", "");
    Log.d("Test", beginD);
```

Log result as follows:

> 06-16 14:14:01.957  23893-23893/packagename D/Test﹕ From
>   16/06/2015, Tue

Comment: check ur output it does not contains From: it only contains FROM no colons.Maybe that will help.Also do not give space after FROM:.Try like replace("From", "").trim();

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to replace `"From:     "` but you only added `"From     "` (without the `:`).

Answer (score 3):

I don't see `:` in the input you entered, so `From:` won't be matched. I recommend using more generic pattern:

```
replaceAll("From:?\\s+", "");
```

Since [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) takes a regex, you can ask for optional `:`, followed by one or more space(s).

Answer (score 1):

In your button text is no `:`. So you have to change the text of the botton to :

```
beginDate.setText("From:     " + dateFormat);
```

or your regex to

```
String beginD = beginDate.getText().toString().replace("From     ", "");
```